# Flash movie hangs up on a specific frame

Tags: flash-cs4

I have a cube where the sides link to more information on the timeline. The information has a close button that returns to the cube on the timeline.   My problem is with the Contact 'side' of the cube.  Clicking on contact goes to the contact information.  Clicking the close button at Contact information occasionally causes the movie to hang up on contact 'side' of the cube.  This is the only place where this occurs and it does not always occur.

Here is a link to the cube: http://www.worldwidego.org/dept404/Cube-test.html

I used Flash CS4 and AS3.  The actionscript is mainly for the buttons  - everything else is created on the timeline.

Any thoughts on what may be causing this would be appreciated.  I can provide the fla file as I know the information here is pretty basic.

Comment: Can you build a simple, self-contained, example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I did find a solution to the issue, but not an answer to the cause.  There are two places on the time line triggering the contact 'side' turning - one turns back, the other next.  I changed the close button to gotoAndPlay the start of the back turn instead of the next turn.  Function is exactly the same and it bypasses the problem frames.  It works fine now.  I may never know the cause of the issue, but I have it resolved.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Same problem again.  It is random, so it may take a while before happening.  I'm now thinking it may be caused by something in the back button frame

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem was in a motion tween layer that was not visible at frame that was hanging up.  I deleted that motion tween and recreated it on a new layer and the hang up was eliminated.